# Python error message ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, string, file, int

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I'm reading data from files, it's all numbers.
I want change it to int, and then it shows this error message.
I tried to use `strip('\n')`, but i still get this error.

```
filename = input('Enter a filename: ')

infile = open(filename,'r')
outfile = open('REPORT-'+filename,'w')

count_year = 0
total_ballots = 0
percentage = 0
less_year= 0

line = infile.readline()
while line !='':
    line=line.strip('\n')
    year = int(infile.readline())
    estimated = int(infile.readline())
    registered = int(infile.readline())
    ballots = int(infile.readline())
    if ((ballots)/(estimated))*100<60:
        less_year +=1
    elif ((ballots)/(estimated))*100>80:
        big_year +=1
    total_ballots = total_ballots + float(ballots)
    outfile.write('In '+ year + ', '+str(format((float(registered)/float(estimated))*100,'.2f')) + 
              '% registered and ' + str(format((float(ballots)/float(estimated))*100,'.2f')) + '% voted')
    percen = format((float(registered)/float(estimated))*100, '.2f')
    percentage = percentage + float(percen)
    count_year +=1
    line=infile.readline()

average = average/count_year

print('The total number of years listed:',count_year)
print('Total ballots cast in all these years:',total_ballots)
print('Average percentage of eligible voters registered:',average,'%')
print('Number of years with less than 60% of registered voters casting ballots:', less_year)
print('Percentage of years with more than 80% of registered voters casting ballots:',(big_year/count_year)*100 )
print('An output file named '+'REPORT-'+filename+' has created.')


infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

here is my input file

```
1958
1703200
1375035
978400
1962
1813500
1446593
971706
1966
1869400
1472054
987134
1970
2078000
1562916
1123000
1974
2419000
1896214
1044425
1978
2651000
1960900
1028854
1982
3119000
2105563
1404831
1986
3307000
2230354
1358160
1990
3650000
2225101
1362651
1994
4000000
2896519
1733471
1998
4257000
3119562
1939421
2002
4519000
3209648
1808720
2006
4821000
3264511
2107370
2010
5149729
3601268
2565589
```

Comment: You must be trying to convert a string or a float or something else: show us what exactly your input is and your code looks like.

Comment: 1958
1703200
1375035
978400

Comment: while line !='':
    line.line.strip('\n')
    year = int(infile.readline())
    estimated = int(infile.readline())
    registered = int(infile.readline())
    ballots = int(infile.readline())

Comment: You better post it in the body of your question and format it correctly, otherwise it's impossible to read.

Comment: Also, the fact that the data comes from a file is irrelevant. If you are in doubt about the content of the string, i.e. because you can't reproduce it without reading it from the file first, use `repr()` to output it. Oh, btw, files feature a line-based iterator interface, so you can write `for line in file: ...`.

Comment: `line.line.strip('\n')` will raise `AttributeError`. This should be `line = line.strip('\n')` (and it's unnecessary since `int()` ignores leading and trailing whitespace. Please also show the input file you're using.

Comment: @user2357112: Not true, he has numerous calls to `readline()` in the `while` loop. But the looping is very wonky, for example, `line` is never actually used.

Comment: You never read in a new value of `line`. If it's nonempty after stripping newlines the first time, it'll never be empty.

Comment: i add line=infile.readline() at the end of while loop  then it shows Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ruihou/Desktop/python/assignment6/assign6.py", line 31, in <module>
    '% registered and ' + str(format((float(ballots)/float(estimated))*100,'.2f')) + '% voted')
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: Yes, like @Emanuele Paolini said, there are probably some other problems with your code as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you keep checking the first line:

```
line = infile.readline()
    while line !='':
```

This condition will never evaluate to `False`, and the loop will keep running indefinitely, because the condition is not being updated in the `while` loop.

Compare:

```
num = 1
while num > 0:
    # do stuff
```

This loop will run forever, unless you modify `num` somewhere in the loop (for example `num -= 1`).

In your case, you loop over your input, until `readline()` gets to the end of the file and returns the empty string. The empty string `''` can not be converted to an integer, obviously, that's why you get the error.

To solve this, I would use a `try ... except ...` block at the beginning:

```
while True:
    try:
        year = int(infile.readline())
    except ValueError:
        break
```

This will make sure that your loop ends when there is no data left to read.

---

As to your other errors, here are some tips:

- Look for variables that need to be strings, but that are integers (like `year`)
- Check for undefined global variables (`big_year`?)
- [Readability counts](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), so put spaces where they belong, which makes debugging so much easier
- Escape percent `%` by doubling it: `%%`

Comment: i added it, but another error shows up              File "C:/Users/ruihou/Desktop/python/assignment6/assign6.py", line 31, in <module>
    '% registered and ' + str(format(ballots/estimate)*100,'.2f') + '% voted')
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: I updated my answer to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your file has an empty line (maybe last line?). That cannot be converted to an int.

There are many other things which have to be corrected anyway, I suspect that the code you have posted should raise many exceptions.